# collaborating code securely

Tags: security, remote-desktop, collaboration

I have recently gotten in touch with a small software company that created a piece of software that I would like to modify and resell under their name.  The CEO has agreed to collaborate with me on this project.  They will provide everything I need to develop and I will develop the software to the liking of a niche market I am close with.  The one condition is the code needs to be secured against theft (from me or any outside entities).  Anything that will prevent the source code or copies of the source code from leaving.

Is it possible to set up a remote server in their office that will limit all network activity except through ports necessary to run the development environment (db, data-feeds)?  Could this be secure enough? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: We occasionally have this problem at work. I tend to recommend either a VPN into their network, or lock down the individual services (sshd, Apache etc.) to only allow certain connections. The VPN solution tends to work the best. You still need to ensure that any local copies you keep are secure.

Comment: @Intermernet So you have run into a similar issue.  Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: We regularly work with 3rd parties on development projects and have found that providing a VPN (IPSEC, PPTP, whatever) connection to the 3rd parties means that they effectively work in our environment. All work is done on systems in our local network and the only way it gets out is if the 3rd party copies it to their machine, or leaks their VPN credentials to someone else.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the 3rd party from copying it to their machine?

Comment: Not really, if they have the ability to view it, they can copy it.